# Update Statement Inside Trigger in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created a insert trigger which has to run some update query once data fully inserted.

```
DDL

    CREATE TABLE DEMO
    (
    MASTERID INT,
    PRICEINCVAT FLOAT,
    [DESC] VARCHAR(50)
    )   
    INSERT DEMO

    SELECT 1000001, 25.69,   '"Bremsbelagsatz, Scheibenbremse " ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000001, 62.58, '"Bremsbelagsatz, Scheibenbremse "   '
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[anUpdate] ON [dbo].[DEMO]
After Insert
AS

set nocount on

BEGIN


UPDATE [dbo].[DEMO]
SET [DESC] = SUBSTRING([DESC], 2, LEN([DESC]))
WHERE LEFT([DESC], 1) = '"'


UPDATE [dbo].[DEMO]
SET [DESC] = SUBSTRING([DESC], 1, LEN([DESC])-1)
WHERE RIGHT([DESC], 1) = '"'
END
```

But trigger failed to fired.

Is there any way to handle this scenario. I want to do this using trigger.
Please share your thoughts.

Expected Value: The Leading and trailing bad character removed from columns.

```
MASTERID    PRICEINCVAT DESC
1000001     25.69       Bremsbelagsatz, Scheibenbremse 
1000001     62.58       Bremsbelagsatz, Scheibenbremse
```

Comment: Any error message you are receiving?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli: No Error Message, but the update is happening on same table on which trigger fire

Comment: Any SQL Server trigger that fails to reference either `inserted` or `deleted` (or both) is probably broken. Here, after any insert to the table, you're going to scan *all of the rows currently contained in the table*, rather than just those which were just inserted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: any way to handle it ?

Comment: Also, do you really want to allow people to insert "wrong" data and silently "correct" it? Far more normal/expected would be to apply a `CHECK` constraint that *prevents people inserting wrong data in the first place*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: 
Check constraint remove the line, but Business Requirement 
is if any such value appear, than correct it before running a report

Comment: Why do you have "BEGIN" after "set nocount on"?   And why don't you have an "END"?

Comment: @TabAlleman: Sorry Typo Error. my bad

Comment: "but trigger failed to fired." Perhaps it's disabled?

Comment: I have to agree that a trigger seems like the wrong tool here. And I strongly dislike changing data silently. Little is more frustrating when using any application than bizarre behavior like that. My guess is your trigger fired but didn't produce the output you are expecting.

Comment: am i missing something to produce the expected output.please suggest

Comment: Trigger is not disabled.

Comment: Yes you are missing.  Why would you not expect that to run on the trigger table?   Why are you updating the whole table?  See the documentation there is an example.

Comment: How about posting the whole trigger? Also posting the ddl for the table would help. And a sample insert statement or value and what you expect after the trigger runs.

Comment: @SeanLange: Thanks Sean. i have added DDL and Trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Damien and Sean that a trigger that alters the values inserted to the table is probably not the best choice, and a check constraint is better.

To add a check constraint you use the `ALTER TABLE` statement - like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MYTABLE_DESC CHECK ([DESC] NOT LIKE '"%' AND [DESC] NOT LIKE '%"');
GO
```

This will prevent any rows where the `[DESC]` column (terrible name, BTW) starts or ends with `"`.

If you really want to use a trigger for insert, here is how I would write it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[anUpdate] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE T
    SET [DESC] = CASE 
                    WHEN I.[DESC] LIKE '"%"' THEN SUBSTRING(I.[DESC], 2, LEN(I.[DESC])-2)
                    WHEN I.[DESC] LIKE '"%' THEN RIGHT(I.[DESC], LEN(I.[DESC])-1)
                    WHEN I.[DESC] LIKE '%"' THEN LEFT(I.[DESC], LEN(I.[DESC])-1)
                    ELSE I.[DESC]
                END,
        Col =  CASE 
                    WHEN I.Col LIKE '"%"' THEN SUBSTRING(I.Col, 2, LEN(I.Col)-2)
                    WHEN I.Col LIKE '"%' THEN RIGHT(I.Col, LEN(I.Col)-1)
                    WHEN I.Col LIKE '%"' THEN LEFT(I.Col, LEN(I.Col)-1)
                    ELSE I.Col
                END
    FROM MYTABLE As T
    -- Assuming your primary key is a column called Id...
    INNER JOIN Inserted AS I ON I.Id = T.Id
    WHERE I.[DESC] LIKE '"%' 
    OR I.[DESC] LIKE '%"'
    OR I.Col LIKE '"%' 
    OR I.Col LIKE '%"';
END
GO
```

Note it only use a single update statement, and it's updating the table using an inner join to the `inserted` pseudo table so it's only effecting new rows.

[You can see a live demo for both options on rextester.](http://rextester.com/AET99420)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will it work if i have to remove bad character from 15 columns.

Comment: @TULSI I'm not sure I understand your comment. my answer is based on the question. It gets the desired results as posted. If you are having problems adapting that to your actual table and data, then perhaps the question is over-simplified.

Comment: To affect 15 columns you would need to address those all in the update statement. But seriously, silently changing data on all the columns is a huge red flag that your application is doing a number of things poorly. This should be fixed in the application and not allow bad data to be entered in the first place. Then a constraint to prevent it from poisoning your database. Changing data silently in a trigger is the wrong place to do this.

Comment: i mean in DDL i have given example with only 1 column DESC, if there are same bad character in other column, will it work i added them in logic.

Comment: You will have to change it a little bit, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I've updated the trigger in the answer as well as the rextester demo. Note that the case expression now have an `else` clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Awesome Learning. Thanks a lot